# Block annoying numbers on freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I use freeswitch and I would like to block some annoying numbers. So far I tried modify inbound_call.xml like this

```
<extension name="annoying1">
  <condition field="destination_number" expression="^5022xxxx$">
    <action application="log" data="NOTICE To jest Rozmowa przych (testowo muzyczka).: ${destination_number}"/>
    <action application="answer"/>
    <action application="playback" data="/home/mwalko/przywitanie.wav"/>
    <action application="hangup"/>
  </condition>
</extension>
```

It doesn't work, should I change this "destination_number"? How can I recognize if for example 5022xxxx calls?

Seems like this "destination_number" points the number which someone called, not the calling one.

Comment: `destination_number` contains the digits entered by the caller, so try out `caller_id_number`. But keep in mind, that this can be faked.

Comment: If you added it as answer, not a comment I would accept it. Works like a charm- thanks.

Comment: Just did it.. Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destination_number` contains the digits entered by the caller, so try out `caller_id_number`. But keep in mind, that this can be faked.

Answer (score 0):

`condition` uses regular expressions for matching, so you need to use a dot (.) instead of "x". You can also use something like `^5022\d{4}$`

Comment: It doesn't work. I have 'full' number- let's assume its 50220000 and I'm sure I can write it like this expression="^50220000$" and I did it like this but unfortunatelly it still possible to make a call.

Comment: Also the order of conditions matters. Maybe there's a matching condition before this one, and it answered the call. You need to look into FreeSWITCH debug log.